# Switching branch issue

Tags: git, branch, checkout

Git: I worked in a local which has deleted from the repository. now I try to checkout to the new branch its showing me the error like there is no branch from the remote.

How do I change to a new branch which is in remote?

Comment: Was the remote branch deleted as well?

Comment: Let's suppose your branch is called `foo`. Do you have a `foo` branch locally? Do you have a `foo` branch on remote?

Comment: I appreciate your response, Mr. @LajosArpad, As you said before, I completed my work on my local branch while it was being removed from Git. Now that I'm attempting to push my most recent changes, an error is being displayed. Another method I tried was stashing first, then trying to switch to a remote branch. In the VS Code terminal, it appeared as though I was in a new branch, but the branch name at the bottom of the left side of the VS Code indicated that I still in the deleted branch.

Comment: Okay, the problem is still unclear to me. Let me break down my questions to small parts. First question: what is the name of your branch?

Comment: @LajosArpad, My branch name is TicketsBug

Comment: @Praveenchris2808 if you run `git branch` in your local repository, do you see `TicketsBug` in the list you receive as an output?